# What's the meaning of 'Last Check-in'?

Tags: chef-infra

When looking at the status tab in the chef server webgui I see some of my nodes have a last check-in of a few minutes ago, even though I haven't ran chef-client in them for days.
Does that mean chef-client is running by itself in some nodes?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It's the last time a "node" (server) sent information to the Chef Server. It's like a healthcheck.

Comment: OK, so it doesn't mean that's  the last time chef-client ran on the node right?

Comment: Yes it does. It's the last time the `chef-client` started

Comment: My client.rb file in one of these nodes is simply

    validation_key "/var/chef/validation.pem"

    client_key "/var/chef/client.pem"
    log_level        :warn
    log_location     "/var/log/chef-warnings.log"
    chef_server_url  "https://chefserver01"
    validation_client_name "chef-validator"

why is chef-client running by itself?

Comment: How did you install it? It could be setup as a service or cron job. There are many ways you can run Chef as a Service

Comment: Just for clarification, it's the last time the `chef-client` run  **completed successfully**. If smth was broken in chef run it will never send node data to server.

Comment: Found out chef-client was registered as a service and that's why it was running every 30min. But the mistery is that several nodes have the same configuration and the chef-client service enabled, but not all of them run chef client every 30 min. Some of these nodes haven't ran chef-client in months....

Answer (score 0):

This isn't quite on topic, but it supports some responses I have seen in this post: You can always add the Chef community "chef-client" cookbook to your role or run_list and it will ensure all nodes check in on an attribute specified fuzzy schedule.

`knife cookbook site install chef-client`

`knife cookbook upload chef-client`

`knife node run_list add $node chef-client`