# Last Check-in keeps on updating in Chef - Scheduling

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

I have removed the chef-client recipe from Node and no roles were assigned to nodes now but still Node is getting scheduled for every 5minutes. 
Role Run_list and Node Run_list are empty.
Please help to find from where scheduling is configured.

Answer (score 0):

having an empty run-list does not disable the execution of chef-client or cause its execution to fail. in such case, chef-client will execute an empty run-list.

each time chef-client is executed, it reports the [`check-in`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22718602/whats-the-meaning-of-last-check-in) and this is what is being reported with [`knife status`](https://docs.chef.io/knife_status.html#examples), which uses the node attribute named [`ohai_time`](https://docs.chef.io/ohai.html#automatic-attributes).

chef-client can [run as a service](https://docs.chef.io/ctl_chef_client.html#run-as-a-service) or [cron](https://linux.die.net/man/8/cron).